# Casting of data to list, came from JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have an entity with the 200 columns with many rows of data, when I run the following JPQL..

```
    StringBuffer nativeQuery = new StringBuffer();
    nativeQuery.append("SELECT b FROM PeopleMaster b WHERE b.gdGrp=?1");

    query = getEntityManager().createQuery(nativeQuery.toString());
    query.setParameter(1, searchParam.getCode());

    List<PeopleMaster> list = query.getResultList();
```

List populate and traverse correctly for the next sections.
Now I have a requirement that I need only one column of data for a dropdown like below..

```
    StringBuffer nativeQuery = new StringBuffer();
    nativeQuery.append("SELECT distinct(b.empId) FROM PeopleMaster b WHERE b.gdGrp=?1");
```

I am aware that assignment of results to `PeopleMaster(List<PeopleMaster> list)` is not compatible as we are only fetching the one column data.

So what is the appropriate way of assignment? do I need to create a new entity with one column and then assign the result to List?

Answer (score 1):

Use [createNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery(java.lang.String)):

```
StringBuffer nativeQuery = new StringBuffer();
nativeQuery.append("SELECT distinct(b.empId) FROM PeopleMaster b WHERE b.gdGrp=?1");
Query q = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(nativeQuery.toString());
query.setParameter(1, searchParam.getCode());

List<Object[]> ids = q.getResultList();

for (Object[] record : ids) {
    System.out.println("Found a distinct employee id: " + record[0]);
}
```

As you can see, the result you get back from `createNativeQuery` is a `List<Object>`, with each record corresponding to an array of objects.  In your case, each record will just have a single column for the ID.

Comment: If you do the same query in JPQL you get back a List of Objects, no need for native for that ...